# Filtering data in LINQ

Tags: sql-server, silverlight, linq

I have an observable collection which would be bound to the silverlight datagrid, where i need to display a particular row based on the data present in the OC

```
ID   Name   Status   Desc   Role
--------------------------------
1    ABC    500      des     50
1    ABC    500      des     55
2    XYZ    502      des     57
```

in the above table there are duplicate values, i need to filter them in such a way that when (status = 500) i need to pick the row which has  role as 50. or if the (status = 501) i need to pick the row which has role  as 55. In any instant the status would remain same for a particular ID. My final data should look like the one below.

```
ID   Name   Status   Desc    Role
---------------------------------
1    ABC    500      des     50
2    XYZ    502      des     57
```

Comment: what is the algorithm for choosing the correct role record - MIN of the records within a distinct ID, Name, Status value?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a fun query by any means.  There may be a better answer, but this should get you started.  The trick here is that you'll need to change your `orderby` clause to meet your needs.  I couldn't tell from your question whether you were trying to pick the min Role value, or were trying to convey something else, but that `orderby` clause is where your custom logic for picking the right record goes.

```
var results =
   from a in DataVals
   group a by new {a.ID, a.Name, a.Status, a.Desc} into g
   select new {
      g.Key.ID,
      g.Key.Name,
      g.Key.Status,
      g.Key.Desc,
      Role = (
         from b in DataVals
         where b.ID == g.Key.ID
         && b.Name == g.Key.Name
         && b.Status == g.Key.Status
         && b.Desc == g.Key.Desc
         orderby b.Role
         select b.Role
      ).Take(1).FirstOrDefault()
   };
```

Comment: its not about picking the minimum value. There is a different logic here, based on the status we have to pick the row from those duplicate records. Say if status is 500 i would pick the row which has role as 50, if status is 501 i had to pick some other role. But i can say only 2 rows would be available for any duplicate record.

Comment: That's still not really enough information to give me the rule to pick the correct role for each status, but this query still works for whatever you're trying to do.  The orderby would just change to something like `orderby b.Status == 500 && b.Role == 50 ? 0 : b.Role` etc etc.